# How to iterate over Table in Jquery to change the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this fiddle

where I have an input type with two buttons `+` and `-` , I want to add the value of the input to all the units value in the table .

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dj23r4af/1/)

The JQuery looks like thi s

```
$(".commission").TouchSpin({
  min: 0,
  max: 2,
  step: 0.0001,
  decimals: 4,
  boostat: 5,
  maxboostedstep: 10,
  buttondown_class: 'btn btn-white',
  buttonup_class: 'btn btn-white'
});
$(".commission").on('touchspin.on.startupspin', function() {
  var table = $(this).parent().parent().parent().prev().find('table');
  console.log(table.rows);
})
```

and the HTML you can see in the fiddle itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/a0a79r7o/6/) with the following code:

```
$(".commission").on('touchspin.on.stopspin', function() {
  var cells = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('table.cust-tbl td');
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    var $cell = cells.eq(i);
    var num = $cell.data('num');
    if (num === undefined || num == null) {
      num = $cell.text().match(/[\d.]+/);
      if (num) {
        $cell.data('num', num[0]);
      }
    }
    num = +$cell.data('num');
    if (num) {
      num += (+$(this).val());
      $cell.text($cell.text().replace(/[\d.]+/, num.toFixed(4)));
    }
  }
});
```

This code stores the original values in a `data` attribute of the cells, and adds the value to that.

Also changed the event to `stopspin`, so that it fires when done selecting value (up or down).

Added rounding to 4 decimals `.toFixed(4)`.

Comment: what is there are many tables in the page ? , How should I focus only the one nearest to the `.commission` class

Comment: @Vikram Change the selector of the table-cells to something unique for that table. -> `table td`

Comment: @Ar0n thats the problem , If there is no usnique id and just have a class say `cust-tbl` , so I was trying to select the table like ` var table = $(this).parent().parent().parent().prev().find('table');` which is like go to the parent to parent of the current elment then get the table from there . But the Object I am getting not able to itterate over that

Comment: @Vikram I changed the selector to `table.cust-tbl td`.

Comment: okay can you fix this fiddle I just updated your code https://jsfiddle.net/a0a79r7o/5/ to show my exact problem

Comment: Just go with this selector then: `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('table td');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145880/discussion-between-vikram-and-arg0n).

Comment: just one more question if I want to add some check like update those td where the value in the span.rate = 'p/kWh' where i would apply

Comment: You can add `:contains("p/kWh")` to the selector: `'table td:contains("p/kWh")'`.

Comment: @Vikram You're missing `td` in the selector.

Comment: Yes got that , I am in hurry to finish this , Very silly mistake

Comment: one more suggestion , what if I have multiple strings like "p/KWH" or "p/kWh" , I tried doing this `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('table.cust-tbl td:contains("p/kWh"):contains("p/KWH")');` doesn't works

Comment: @Vikram Separate selectors with comma `,`: `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('table td:contains("p/kWh"), table td:contains("p/KWH")');`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the plugin you are using, so I'll put my function inside a `.change()` but put this code inside the function called at each input change :

```
$('body').on('change','.commission',function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $('.unit').each(function(){
    $(this).text(+$(this).text()+$this.val());
  });
});
```

Comment: can you edit the fiddle itself and let me know , All I am trying to do is add the value of the commission to the unit value in the table